# Get an id to another page

Tags: php, mysql

Hello this is my first post here, I need your help.

First of all, I want to say sorry for my bad English. I hope you will understand me :D

So, I'm a newbie in php and I have a problem.
I want to take the id from a file, to another file, but I don't know how. I will show you my code below.

```
            while($array = $db->get_row($row))
        {
            $id = $array['id'];
            $Nume = $array['user_name'];
            $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $array['date']);;
            $stitle = $array['shorttext'];
            $text = $array['text'];
            $logs .= '
                <div class="post">
                    <div class="post-meta clearfix">
                        <h4 class="post-title left">
                            <a href="/index.php?page=news id='.$id.'">'.$stitle.'</a>
                            </h4>
                            <p class="post-info right">
                            <span>'.$Nume.'</span>
                            '.$date.'
                            </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="post-box">
                            <div class="post-content">
                            <div class="post-intro">
                            '.$text.'
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="post-footer clearfix">
                            <div class="continue-reading">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                ';
        }
```

Here where is ID, I want to take that id to the news page. (the code is in index.php)

```
<a href="/index.php?page=news?id='.$id.'">'.$stitle.'</a>
```

In news.php have to select from mysql all but only the table with the ID from index.php

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $row = $db->sql("SELECT * FROM `ucp_news` WHERE `id` = '".$id."' ");
    $array = $db->get_array($row);
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Change `?page=news id=` to `?page=news&id=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code is correct, although you should be using `htmlspecialchars()` when adding the variables to the output. This to prevent XSS attacks, and the like.

Though, your problem lies most likely in this line:

```
<a href="/index.php?page=news id='.$id.'">
```

More specifically, the missing ampersand (&) between `news` and `id`. Try to look at the value of `$_GET['page']` when clicking on the link, then you should see what the problem is.